# Express: unable to access route from browser due to accept:application/javascript header missing

Tags: express, webpack

I'm new to express. I have a Vue application running on express. I have some API routes that I'm able to access using axios through the browser. To access those routes using postman I have to have the header:

```
accept: application/javascript
```

for it to return the result of the actual API. If I don't use this header, I get the generated index.html from webpack. I need to reuse one of these routes to return excel/pdf, based on a parameter and have it accessible via a link on the page.

Here's my server.js - based on https://github.com/southerncross/vue-express-dev-boilerplate

```js
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
import logger from 'morgan'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import webpack from 'webpack'

const argon2 = require('argon2');
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require ('passport-local')
const session = require('express-session')


import history from 'connect-history-api-fallback'

// Formal(Prod) environment, the following two modules do not need to be introduced
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware'

import config from '../../build/webpack.dev.conf'

const app = express()
app.set('trust proxy', true)

app.set("view engine", "pug")
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use ('/', require('./routes'))


app.use(session({
 secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'secretsauce',
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: true
}))


app.use(history())
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')))
app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: false
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

const compiler = webpack(config)

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
 publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
 stats: {
  colors: true
 }
}))

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))



////////// PASSPORT ///////////////////////
app.use (passport.initialize ());
app.use (passport.session ());

async function authenticateUser (username, password) {
//...
  
}

passport.use (
 new LocalStrategy (async (username, password, done) => {
  const user = await authenticateUser (username, password)
  if (!user) {
   return done (null, false, {
    message: 'Username and password combination is wrong',
   });
  }

  delete user.password;
  return done (null, user)
 })
);

// Serialize user in session
passport.serializeUser ((user, done) => {
 done (null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser (function(user, done) {
 if(user === undefined || !user || Object.keys(user).length === 0)
  return done(null, false)
 else
  done (null, user);
});

//////////// passport end ///////////////


app.set("view engine", "pug")
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')))
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile('./views/index.html')
})
app.get('/success', function (req, res) {
 res.render('./views/success')
})



app.use ('/api', require('./api'))


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 var err = new Error('Not Found')
 err.status = 404
 next(err)
})

app.use(function (err, req, res) {
 res.status(err.status || 500)
 res.send(err.message)
})




let server = app.listen(80)

export default app
```

And here's a bit of **api.js**

```js
const {Router} = require ('express')
const router = Router()

router.get('/whome', function(req, res){
 logger.info('whome', req.user)
 return res.json(req.user)
})


router.get ('/hello', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
 res.json ({text:'hello'})
})

module.exports = router
```

I can call `http://localhost/api/hello` from postman with the `accept:application/javascript` header and I get:

```
{
    "text": "hello"
}
```

as expected. But if I call the same URL from the browser (and it's not sending that header), I get the created bundle index.html. How can I access these routes from the browser?

Comment: In your browser application are you sure that you're calling the api endpoint correctly? And are you using hash routing or history routing? If you're using history routing I suspect it might have something to do with the `'connect-history-api-fallback'` package. Try removing it and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First one, try to add this in your server:

`app.options('*', cors())`

before to: `app.set("view engine", "pug")`

If that doesnt work, try to install this `addon`  in your `Google Chrome browser` to test.

[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

And enable it. (The icon should be green instead of red).

Why this happens? 
The request that's being made is called a preflight request.
Preflight requests are made by the browser, as CORS is a browser security restriction only - This is why it works in Postman, which is, of course, not a browser.

Reference: [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)